Mixing useNavigate with useHistory in React
In my current workplace, the project that I am supposed to work on has used useHistory up to now. I know that in newer versions it is usually better to use useNavigate. Would it be okay (non-breaking) to start using useNavigate inside of my new components without changing the older components to use useNavigate.
I am worried that the components will have unexpected bugs that are hard to track later on if I break the convention.


I know that in newer versions it is usually better to use useNavigate.
Would it be okay (non-breaking) to start using useNavigate inside of
my new components without changing the older components to use
useNavigate.

React-Router v5 doesn't export any useNavigate hook, and React-Router v6 hasn't any useHistory export, and you can't have react-router-dom@5 and react-router-dom@6 installed at the same time. You can however use the react-router-dom-v5-compat Backwards Compatibility Package to bridge this gap during the upgrade migration.
The basic migration path would resemble the following:

Ensure your project is on React 16.8 or higher

Install the compatibility package
Run npm install react-router-dom-v5-compat

Render the compatibility router


Incrementally upgrade what you want/need
Replace history with navigate.



Of course react-router-dom-v5-compat is only meant and intended to be a temporary solution, you should plan to complete the upgrade to React-Router-DOM 6 as quickly as possible and remove the compatibility package.

Uninstall compatibility package
npm uninstall react-router-dom-v5-compat

Uninstall react-router (v5) and history (if you have it)
npm uninstall react-router history

Install React-Router 6
npm install react-router-dom@6

Remove the CompatRouter and clean up the imports (i.e. all imports from react-router-dom)



